# With ASP .NET, how do I display a side submenu depending on what user picked from the main menu?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I come from PHP side, but I'm in need to develop a site using ASP .NET

So far I manage to create a master page. Now I'm dealing with menus and submenus

What I'm trying to do is, if the user picks "About Us" from the main menu, under the about us page I want to display a submenu with the options "who we are, what we do, contact us"

If the user picks "Our Products" from the main menu, then under the products page I want to display a submenu with the options "product 1, product 2, product 3"

Is this possible with only one master page?

I read something about menu control but not sure that is what I need. So far I found how to display a sitemap, but not specific sections of a sitemap, if this is the way to do things.

Any links, sample code, point of reference will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is this asp.net webforms or asp.net mvc?

Comment: I did not know there is a difference. I'm just using .aspx file extension. Like I said, I come from the PHP side so all this is new for me.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I'd look at is using JavaScript to display the selected menu items without a postback.

I'd need more information on how your main menu is hooked up though.

Comment: The main menu is just a list. <ul><li><a href>About us</a></li></ul>, then if I'm in the about us page, I want to display a submenu on the sidebar. The main menu has no relationship with anything. I was thinking on just do like 5 different submenu html files, and call them as needed. But not sure how to include html files with asp.

Comment: If the submenu is naturally associated with a page, then yes I would do it that way. If all menus should be accessible from any page (a typical case), then I would review this design.

Comment: So how can I associate a submenu with a page? and with just one master page? I'm trying to avoid to create a master page for each section, since the layout is the same, the only difference is the submenu, and content.

Comment: Add it to the content page. Also, if it better suites your design, you can nest master pages. So you could have a master page than inherits from your base master page but just adds a submenu. But, given your description, it seems like it'd be easier to add the submenu to the content page. Add a content placeholder in your master page if that helps.

Comment: For what? Creating a content placeholder? No code needed, just drag a content placeholder from the toolbox to a webform.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably write a separate web User Control to handle the menu and just include it in your Master page as usual.

A simple way is to use a `Placeholder` control in side which you write the markup for each menu set you want to include. Set their `Visible` property to false in the markup (.ascx file).

`<asp:Placeholder runat='server' id='phAbout' Visible='false'>

<a href='/about/index.aspx'>Information about Us</a>

<a href='/about/us.aspx'>About Us</a>

</asp:Placeholder />`

Then, at `Page_Load time`, do some processing, for exampl examine the Request.Path property to work out what sub-directory the current page is in etc. Then run a bit of logic to show the relevant menus by setting the associated `Placeholder`'s `Visible` property to true.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each of your main menu item contains a group of pages.

Create a sitemap file to describe the whole site and all menus.  And while each page is loading, site map gives you the current node from the map, which is the current page.

You can easily construct the submenus by walking through the nodes in any page/master page.